# Polynomial variable of inapproximability after reduction

Tags: reductions, approximation

I proved the inapproximability of a problem that, given a multigraph $G = (V, E)$ and a set of vertices $U \subseteq V$ tries to maximize a score $f(U)$ whose value depends on the edges of the graph, so it takes values in $\{0, \dots, m\}$, $m$ being the number of edges in the graph.

As the result was obtained by (exactly) reducing from the Maximum Independent Set which is known for being inapproximable within $n^{1- \epsilon}$, I am not sure how this is translated to my problem: Is it inapproximable within $n^{1- \epsilon}$ or within $m^{1- \epsilon}$ (as, in a certain sense, it counts the number of edges)?

(In the proof we build a multigraph in which each edge contributing to the score is associated with an independent vertex in the original graph and vice versa)

Comment: The answer depends on your reduction. Can you spell out the properties satisfied by your reduction? That is, what is the relation between $\max f(U)$ and the size of the maximum independent set?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus they are exactly equal to each other: $f(U) = |S|$ if $S$ is the independent set

Comment: What is the number of vertices in the output of the reduction?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus From a graph $G$ with $|V|$ vertices I build a multigraph with $|V| + 2$ vertices

Comment: The $n$ in the inapproximability result for maximum independent set is the number of vertices. What I would suggest is writing out what it means for maximum independent set to be inapproximable within $n^{1-\epsilon}$, and then using your reduction to prove an inapproximability result for your problem. Instead of guessing what you get, prove it.

Comment: Then if I am correct my problem should be inapproximable within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ basically because if it was inapproximable within $m^{1-\epsilon}$ then when going back from the reduction we would have a different inapproximability for the MIP

Comment: If you’re not sure, write a complete proof. It would just be a few sentences.